# Calculating rotation angle X-Y-Z

Tags: math, calculator

There's a mobile phone simulator which simulates phones rotation angle (accelerometer).
The user gives it X-Y-Z rotation which are between -180 and 180 and the result is a number between -1 and 1.

I need to do the same thing in my current project.

Here are some examples.

Example number 1: 
    X = -80 , 
    Y = 140 , 
    Z = -120
And the result: 
    X = 0.66g , 
    Y = -0.64g , 
    Z = -0.4g

Example number 2: 
    X = 90 , 
    Y = 15 , 
    Z = -100 , 
And the result: 
    X = -0.95g , 
    Y = 0.25g , 
    Z = 0.17g

I'v been searching for 2 days with no luck. Hope someone can help me here.

Answer (score 0):

Just an intuitive answer: 
Your X, Y, Z are basically polar(spherical) coordinates. You can apply a Jacobi transformation to convert them to a cartesian space. Then multiply it with some random(or meaningful) speed vector to get sort of a correlated fake acceleration.